# Start a script manually without load it

Tags: php, cron, load, jobs

I need to reduce the loading time of a page that has to load a thousand files to make a ranking by starting a script manually but without loading it (like a cron job started manually).

Is there a way to do that using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to start a script execution when the user wants in the background you could use php exec(); example:

```
<?php
$cmd = "php /path/to/php/script/ &> /dev/null &";
exec('/bin/bash -c "' . addslashes($cmd) . '"');
```

(Not 100% positive on the syntax for the $cmd it could be /usr/bin/php or something similar or it could be php5 depending on your system.)

Comment: It can be limited by your server's setup or permissions. If your script isn't executing as root try changing its chown and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

can you elaborate a bit more on that? you could always run a cron job for your php script if you have an apache server

Comment: I have to execute the script in the background

Answer (score 0):

You can run php from shell with "php filename.php" and you can do this with a cron job. But I'm not sure if that is what you want maybe have a look at opt cache to make your site faster.

Comment: How do I run the script form shell?